# Javascript / JQuery: How do I count the words separated with a comma?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, count

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#field').keyup(function()
    {
        var count = '??';

        $('#count').html(count);
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="field" /> <span id="count">5</span>
```

Examples (words are always separated with a comma):

```
example 1: word, word word
count: (5 - 2) = 3

example 2: word
count: (5 - 1) = 4

example 3: word, word,
count: (5 - 2) = 3

example 4: word, word, word
count: (5 - 3) = 2
```

So, I need to count how many words there are separated with a comma, but for example as shown in **example 3**, it should not count them as **3 words** only when there is a word also AFTER a comma.

And a user should not be allowed to enter more than 5 words.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Something like:

```
$("#input").keyup(function(){
    var value = $(this).val().replace(" ", "");
    var words = value.split(",");

    if(words.length > 5){
        alert("Hey! That's more than 5 words!");
        $(this).val("");
    }
});
```

jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/BzN5W/

**EDIT:**

Better example: http://jsfiddle.net/BzN5W/2/

```
$("#input").keypress(function(e){
    var value = $(this).val().replace(" ", "");
    var words = value.split(",");

    if(words.length > 5){
        //alert("Hey! That's more than 5 words!");
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: No problem ;) Don't forget to check my answer.

Comment: Of course not lol, I just had to wait for another minute ;) thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

`words.split(",").length` should give you what you want, where `words` is a string containing the input.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this:

```
$('#field').keyup(function(e){
    var count = $(this).val().split(',').length;
    $('#count').html(count);
    if(count > 4)
        e.preventDefault();
});
```